# jqueryui autocomplete and txt file

Tags: jquery, file, text, autocomplete

I've got these .txt file:

```
one;uno
two;dos
three;tres
four;cuatro
```

And this html script:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

How could I write the items of the first column of the .txt in the brackets of

```
var availableTags = [ ];
```

UPDATE: this doesn't seem to be the correct way to to call the .txt file:

```
<script>

$.get('dicc.txt', function(data) {

var i;
var pos = 0;
var availableTags = [];

x = x.split(/[\;,\n]+/);

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i = i + 2)
  availableTags[pos++] = x[i];

console.log(availableTags);

$(function() {
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});

}, 'text');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'text'` datatype in your `$.get()` request. Otherwise jQuery guesses at what was returned.

Try the following:

```
$.get('source_file.txt', function(data) {
  var i;
  var pos = 0;
  var availableTags = [];

  data = data.split(/[\;,\n]+/); //split text using regex (separators: ';' and '\n')

  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 2)
     availableTags[pos++] = x[i];

}, 'text');
```

Since, I don't have access to any text file, I've made an example of jQueryUI Autocomplete using a string:

```js
var x = "one;uno\ntwo;dos\nthree;tres\nfour;cuatro";

var i;
var pos = 0;
var availableTags = [];

x = x.split(/[\;,\n]+/);

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i = i + 2)
  availableTags[pos++] = x[i];

console.log(availableTags);

$(function() {
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Here's working a **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/licigi/edit?html,js,console,output)**. Observe how the values are stored in `availableTags` in the Console tab.

Remember, `$.get` is just a convenience wrapper for `$.ajax`. The datatypes are listed in the [`$.ajax()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

And yes, welcome to the community! ;)

Comment: First of all thank you. As you can see i'm not a master of code. I placed your script between the two brackets of mine [between lines 3 and 4] and ir doesn't work. It works when i write the items between those brackets, but i need to find a way toread it from the txt

Comment: You're not supposed to put this code between the square braces `[ ]`. Put this code between `<script>` and `</script>`. And replace `source_file.txt` with the path of your actual file (if this code file is in the same folder as the text file, then simply write your_file_name.txt). It'll definitely work, I've tested it. ;) And please accept my answer by clicking on the check mark once you get this code working.

Comment: theScorpion, I'm so so happy with your help and simplicity of your language, you're lovely :). However I keep on having problems with this code :`(. I'm using this code www.jqueryui.com/autocomplete and the function autocomplete doesn't appear in your answer... don't get angry with me!!

Comment: Check the edit and a working demo in my answer. Hope it clarifies your autocomplete issue. :)

Comment: Haha... what happened now?! :P